# How to make Solr spellcheck work all the time?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I want to use Solr spellcheck to find similar words. However when I enter a word which is 'known' to Solr, spellcheck is not returning anything. Is there a way to make spellcheck work even if word is found with an exact match?

Answer (score 2):

The thing closest to what you are looking for is probably setting [onlyMorePopular](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.onlyMorePopular) to true.

Comment: Yes, you are right onlyMorePopular does something similar. I ended up adding '~' at the end of my query to remove exact matching. Not an elegant solution, but it seem to do what I need